# Using raphael.js to draw an image with parameters sent through socket.io

Tags: javascript, image, socket.io, raphael

This is what I have tried so far.

`socket-server.js`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var config = require('./config2.js');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('socket-client.html');
});
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    var mapRes = {width : 720, height: 1040};
    socket.emit("mapRes", mapRes);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Relevent scripts from `socket-client.html`

```
var socket = io();
window.onload = function() {
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), canvas_width, canvas_height);
    socket.on('mapRes', function(message){
    var mapRes = message;
    var mapImg = paper.image("http://localhost/home/username/Desktop/map.png",0,0,mapRes.width,mapRes.height);
    });
}
```

Here, "canvas" just an id of the  tag where the image is supposed to be loaded

Although the console showed `GET http://localhost/home/username/Desktop/map.png [0ms]`, the image is not loaded.
both the image and the codes (`socket-server.js` & `socket-client.html`) are in the same folder as the `map.png`.The complete path to folder is `/home/username/Desktop`. Can someone enlighten me on where I got it wrong?

Comment: What is 'canvas' here ? Normally with Raphael you would pass it an 'id' rather than an element itself (it may still work though, just I haven't seen it done that way).

Comment: "canvas" is the `id` of the `<div>` tag where I wanna load the image :)

Comment: If you output mapRes to the console before the paper.image line, what is its contents ?

Comment: `Object {width:720,height:1040}`
It's correct. The only problem is the "path of the image", I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a folder under the same folder as the script files and name it as "public" (or whatever you'd like).

On your `socket-server.js`,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public')); //let express access your "public" folder.
```

On your `client.html`,

```
var mapImg = paper.image("./map.png",x,y,width,height);
```

Paper will try to load your image from your "public" folder.
FYI, "http:" won't be able to access your local files(from local HDD) for security reasons.